# How can I get my adjusted P values in matrix form?

Tags: r, statistics, posthoc

I want a simple table of adjusted P values that I can export to Excel. However, as in the screenshot

[image]

the adjusted p values are coming out not in an 184x184 matrix like everything else, but instead two columns. How do I fix this? The code I used to get this info is with the psych package:

```
corr.test(braakxsymptoms,method="spear
man",adjust="fdr", alpha=.05, ci=TRUE)
```

See that every other output but p.adj is 184x184.

I tried to get a 184x184 grid but instead got an output in two columns.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: Thanks. I don’t know how to get the desired output, that’s my question.

Comment: Could you supply a small example (say with 10 rows rather than 184) that results in two columns rather than whatever you get? This will allow readers to play around with your data/code and see how to get the results you are seeking.

Comment: (Note that images are a poor way to show this, as the text within cannot be copy-pasted).